# how can create top border in TemplateField element?

Tags: c#

I create `TemplateField` in my project  and I need to set top border of `TemplateField`.

Here I declare  `TemplateField`:

```
  var myFooterTemplate = new TemplateField();
```

and here is how I try to create top border:

```
   myFooterTemplate.ItemStyle.CssClass =  "border-top: solid red;";
```

But this attitude doesn't work.

Any idea how can create top border in `TemplateField` element?

Comment: Why CssClass? Maybe Style property?

Comment: @Maxim, can you plaese show  example how do I create a  style in c#?

Comment: As I can see "border-top: solid red;" is style string, but used for property named CssClass. But text "border-top.." is not CSS class name. Try to look here: https://forums.asp.net/t/1691125.aspx?Change+ItemStyle+Css+Class+in+the+Code+Behind